# EXCEL VBA Run Solver Using a Loop for Multiple Rows

Tags: vba, excel, optimization, solver

I've recorded a macro to run solver on excel, and now need it to loop to run on a range of rows (54 to 288) with the necessary parameters.

I'm trying to minimise Col. CQ, by changing Cols. CF:CJ (which SHOULD be allowed to be negative)
and adding 2 constraints:

- Col CM must be = 1
- Col CQ must >= 0

Help is much appreciated! Please find the code below.

```
SolverOk SetCell:="CQ54", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="CF54:CJ54" _
    , Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverAdd CellRef:="CM54", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="1"
SolverAdd CellRef:="CQ54", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
SolverOk SetCell:="CQ54", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="CF54:CJ54" _
    , Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverOk SetCell:="CQ54", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="CF54:CJ54" _
    , Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverSolve
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
For n = 54 to 288
    SolverReset
    SolverOk SetCell:="CQ" & n, MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, _
         ByChange:="CF" & n & ":CJ" & n , Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="CM" & n, Relation:=2, FormulaText:="1"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="CQ" & n, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"

    SolverSolve
Next n
```